# not getting spcified index answer in html javascript

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

i am working on project i am working with if quantity change then total will change i am working with this method with help of local storage its showing correct in local storage but not getting answer correct

```
const input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'number';
// input.value = 1;
input.value = element.quantity;
console.log(element.quantity);

input.setAttribute('id', 'need')
input.addEventListener('change', changeQuantity);

function changeQuantity() {
  var quantity = Number(document.getElementById('need').value);
  console.log(quantity);
  console.log(typeof(quantity));

  if (quantity === 0) {
    removeItem();
  } else {
    console.log(index);
    wishlist[index].quantity = quantity;

    localStorage.setItem('wishlist', JSON.stringify(wishlist));
    displayData(wishlist);
  }

  console.log(document.getElementById('need').value);
}
```

[image]

in this pic if i am trying to change second product it will not change i can change only value of first product and after that if i am changing second proctuct value its taking value of firt product.

[image]

[image]

Comment: IDs need to be unique. You can't use the same `id="need"` for all the inputs.

Comment: In the event listener, `event.target` will be the input that was edited, you don't need to use `getElementById()`.

Comment: so what shoul i do to resolve this?

Comment: I just told you: Add the `event` parameter to `changeQuantity`, then use `event.target.value`.

Comment: i am just learning web development could you explain by syntecally please?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have duplicate IDs, so you can't use the same ID `need` for all the inputs. Use `event.target` to get the current input in the `changeQuantity()` function.

It looks like there are other problems in the code. I don't see where you get `index` from. And how is `removeItem()` supposed to know which item to remove?

```js
function changeQuantity(event) {
  var quantity = Number(event.target.value);
  console.log(quantity);
  console.log(typeof(quantity));

  if (quantity === 0) {
    removeItem();
  } else {
    console.log(index);
    wishlist[index].quantity = quantity;

    localStorage.setItem('wishlist', JSON.stringify(wishlist));
    displayData(wishlist);
  }

}
```

Comment: thank you so so much i totally got it you saved me...